# Rails 3 Routes Help

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

this is probably simple, but I can't figure it out.

I'm trying to create a route to :submissions#new via the url "/submit"

```
resources :submissions, :only => [:index, :show, :new, :create]
match 'submit', :to => 'submissions#new'
```

The code above works fine, but I want to block the standard "resources" created URL of 
"/submissions/new" and only use the "/submit" URL.  The way I have it written both URLs will render submissions#new, which I don't want.

When I comment out the "resources" line of code and only use the "match" line, it can no longer find the controller "submissions_controller"

Here is the error message:

ActionController::RoutingError in Submissions#new

Showing /media/sf_admin/Projects/lolsnort/app/views/submissions/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

No route matches {:controller=>"submissions"}

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your _form.html.erb contents?

Comment: No need, Surya answered it.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way out:

```
resources :submissions, :except => [:new]
match 'submit', :to => 'submissions#new', :as => :submit
```